Error Message: Error in checkInput(y, times, func, rtol, atol, jacfunc, tcrit, hmin, : `hmax' must be a non-negative value
I am currently trying to run a model with the script written below. However, I keep on getting this error message which I have put in the title but will still down here for clarity. I have tried changing the times, state, params and even the method of the ode solver but nothing seems to be working. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you very much.
neonateWeight <- 1.1
reproductiveWeight <- 7.5
maximumWeight <- 60.0
instarDuration <- 3.0

ksFood <- 85.0
IngestWeight <-132.0
maxIngest <- 1.05
assimilEff <- 0.8
maxReproduction <- 0.8
respirationRate <- 0.25

transferTime <- 2
foodInMedium <- 509
numberIndividuals <- 32

state <-c(INDWEIGHT = neonateWeight ,
          EGGWEIGHT = 0 ,
          FOOD = foodInMedium)

model <-function(t,state,parameters)
  {
  with(as.list(c(state)),{
  WeightFactor <- (IngestWeight-INDWEIGHT)/(IngestWeight-neonateWeight)
  MaxIngestion <- maxIngest*WeightFactor
  Ingestion <- MaxIngestion*INDWEIGHT*FOOD / (FOOD + ksFood)
  Respiration <- respirationRate * INDWEIGHT
  Growth <- Ingestion*assimilEff - Respiration
  if (Growth <= 0. | INDWEIGHT < reproductiveWeight)
  Reproduction <- 0. else
    {
    WeightRatio <- reproductiveWeight/INDWEIGHT
  Reproduction <- maxReproduction * (1 - WeightRatioˆ2)
}
  dINDWEIGHT <- (1 - Reproduction) * Growth
  dEGGWEIGHT <- Reproduction * Growth
  dFOOD <- -Ingestion * numberIndividuals
  list(c(dINDWEIGHT, dEGGWEIGHT, dFOOD),
  c(Ingestion = Ingestion,
    Respiration = Respiration,
    Reproduction = Reproduction))
  }) 
}

Moulting <- function ()
  {
  with(as.list(c(state)),{
    refLoss <- 0.24
    cLoss <- 3.1
    INDLength <- (INDWEIGHT /3.0)^(1/2.6) #Mariam
    WeightLoss <- refLoss * INDLength^cLoss
return(INDWEIGHT - WeightLoss)   
})  
}

TimeFrom <- 0
TimeEnd <- 40
TimeMoult <- TimeFrom + instarDuration
TimeTransfer <- TimeFrom + transferTime
Time <- TimeFrom
Outdt <- 0.1
out <- NULL

while (Time < TimeEnd)
{
TimeOut <- min(TimeMoult,TimeTransfer,TimeEnd)
times <- seq(Time,TimeOut,by=Outdt)
out1 <- as.data.frame(ode(state,times,model,parms=0))
out <- rbind(out,out1)
lout <- nrow(out1) # last element of output
state <-c(
INDWEIGHT = out1[lout,"INDWEIGHT"],
EGGWEIGHT = out1[lout,"EGGWEIGHT"],
FOOD = out1[lout,"FOOD"])
  if (Time >= TimeMoult)
  {
  state[1] <- Moulting() # Moulting...
  state[2] <- 0 # Eggs = 0
  TimeMoult <- Time +instarDuration # next moult time
  }
  if (Time >= TimeTransfer) 
  {
  state[3] <- foodInMedium
  TimeTransfer <- Time + transferTime 
  }
  Time <- TimeOut
}

plot (out$time,out$FOOD ,type="l",main="Food",
xlab="time, days",ylab="μgC/l")
plot (out$time,out$INDWEIGHT,type="l",main="individual weight",
xlab="time, days",ylab="μgC")
plot (out$time,out$EGGWEIGHT ,type="l",main="egg weight",
xlab="time, days",ylab="μgC")
plot (out$time,out$Ingestion ,type="l",main="Ingestion",
xlab="time, days",ylab="μgC/ind/day")
mtext(outer=TRUE,side=3,"DAPHNIA model",cex=1.5)


If not specified, hmax is set to the largest difference in times, to avoid that the simulation possibly ignores short-term events.. I suggest you print the times vector. Are its elements perhaps not strictly increasing?

Yes I checked it and the value of times is 2 and seems not to be increasing, however if I use TimeOut <- min(TimeMoult,TimeTransfer,TimeEnd), I get a 400 vector output as times.

There cannot be just one value in times. ode expects more values.

I understand, in ideal conditions I should get a sequence of numbers with code times <- seq(Time,TimeOut,by=Outdt) which should be by default from 0 to 2 with a step of 0,1 .However, I keep getting the single value of 2 which should not be the case and I don't understand why?

That would happen if Time and TimeOut are equal.

Well, they are indeed equal, I still don't understand what is going on and how Time changed from 0 to 2 because it is equal to TimeFrom which is 0. If you have any suggestions on how I can improve the code or what I can do to fix this, it will be much appreciated. Thank you so much for all your suggestions.

Looks like you need to debug the code in your while loop.

Thank you very much. I have been able to debug it but not solve the problem, the issue is with the updated expression Time <- TimeOut.

I have been able to solve this, apparently there was an if statement needed in between times and the first if statement.
The if statement goes thus:
if (length(times)>1) {
  out1    <-as.data.frame(ode(state,times,model,parms=0))  # integrate
  out     <- rbind(out,out1)                                 # add output to output array
  lout    <- nrow(out1)                                      # last element of output
  state   <-c(
             INDWEIGHT = out1[lout,"INDWEIGHT"],
             EGGWEIGHT = out1[lout,"EGGWEIGHT"],
             FOOD      = out1[lout,"FOOD"])
  }```

